# some assembly language syntax definition

Tags: assembly

I have had my third assembly language class and my teacher asked me about this line of code.
is there anyone who explains this line in details? I am a real noob in this language. please speak as simple as you can.

```
    myMessage BYTE "He says, ",22h,"Hello, World!",22h,0dh,0ah,0
```

Answer (score 1):

This line defines array of bytes, characters. It's similar to, in C:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

BYTE myMessage[] = "He says, \x22Hello, World!\x22\r\n";
```

`22h` is `"` and `0dh` is `\r` and `0ah` is `\n`. The last `0` is a NULL byte that terminates the string. Look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Side note: \r\n is return/line feed = new line character combination for Microsoft based operating systems.